# NodeJS cannot find Express module on Raspberry

Tags: node.js, express, raspberry-pi3, npm-install

I'm testing a simple NodeJS app in my Raspberry but I can't get it working. I developed and tested in my Windows 10 and it works great, but when I move the files into the Raspberry it says node can't find express module:

**EDIT: I've re-upload the image since I mistaken the previous**

[image: node app.js]

Data:

> - Raspberry Pi Model: 3B V1.2
> - OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
> - NodeJS: v8.11.3
> - NPM: 5.6.0

I've read another questions and try the next steps (without success):

> - npm install
> - sudo npm install
> - npm install express
> - sudo npm install express
> - npm install express --save

In my *node_modules* folder it seems to be everything ok:

[image: node_modules folder]

My folders structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is typo. You are trying to use `Express` not `express`

NodeJS are case sensitive, so you have to make sure that your character are in the same case.

Comment: I upload the wrong capture, sorry! Now it shows the right error.

Comment: I edited my answer please have a looks @AndrésMarotta

Comment: This is not an answer, should be a comment

Comment: Well, turns out that I'm an idiot, xD. That was the problem, now it's working! What I don't understand is why it works in my local machine, I guess it's an OS issue. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you are using window right ? @AndrésMarotta

Comment: @Natsathorn yes I am.

Comment: @AndrésMarotta for windows it doesn't matter which case you use, but for linux it is. That's why it work on you machine,,

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find `app.js`... Because there is none in this folder ;)

You're trying to launch your `app.js` while `cd`d in your `node_modules` folder.
The way node modules work is that they'll be installed in a `node_modules` folder that you can then access app-wise by either `require`ing them (CommonJS) or `import`ing them (ESModules). 
Here, it seems like you're just in the wrong cd, simple as that.

Comment: Wrong screenshot, sorry! I'll change it rigth now, but that's not the problem, :(